# VBA: Trying to keep defined variable when calling a sub from another module

Tags: vba, variables, module

I have a sub, Sub1, in Module1, that defines Variable1. In Module1 I have publicly declared Variable1. In Sub1, I call a separate Sub, Sub2, after Variable1 is defined. Sub2 is in Module2. In Module2 I have also publicly declared Variable1.

I get an error when I try to run Sub1:

> Run-time error '91':
>
> Object variable or With block variable not set

I have tested this with putting Sub2 within Module1, and then Sub1 runs correctly. What can I do to keep Sub2 in its own module and still maintain the set variable? Thank you.

Edit: Sorry, I will try to write a sample code as the actual one is much more complex than what I'm talking about here and contains identifying information.

**Module 1**

```
Public ws1 As Worksheet


Sub1()
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Call Sub2()
End Sub
```

**Module 2**

```
Public ws1 As Worksheet


Sub2()
ws1.Activate
End Sub
```

It is at the *ws1.Activate* in Sub2 that I get Run-time error '91'. It seems that VBA has lost the defined ws1 that was set in the parent Sub1.

Comment: post the code please as your description is very hard to read.

Comment: Sorry, updated.

Comment: If you always run `Sub1` from **Module 1** before you run `Sub2` it works just fine, jut remove `Public ws1 As Worksheet` from **Module 2**. One more thins, I hope the name of your sub is not `Sub1` and `Sub2` because it won't run. Maybe you mean `Sub Sub1` and `Sub Sub2` ?

Comment: When I remove that `Public ws1` from **Module2**, I get the Ambiguous Name Detected error on `ws1.Activate` instead of Run-time error '91'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting it here, since it's too long to put as a comment.

**Module 1**

```
Option Explicit

Public ws1 As Worksheet

Sub Sub1()

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Sub2

End Sub
```

**Module 2**

```
Sub Sub2()

' add this line to debug, when you type Module3 you will get 
' all variable within Module 3
Debug.Print Module3.ws1.Name
ws1.Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I have done this, but when I run Sub1 I still get the error: `Ambiguous name detected: ~`. It highlights `Sub Sub2()` in yellow and selects the text of `ws1.Activate`

Comment: Hey, I am checking yours as the answer because your original comment got me thinking. I have another module with public variables defined. That was the thing that was bringing up the ambiguous name detection error. Thank you!